# jQuery Ajax success submit condition issue

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a form that I submit to a php file, the php file will check if the record exists or not. If it exists it will echo "Already Exists". In my ajax "success" it does see the "Already Exist" but when I place a condition it does not work. For example under success in my ajax function I placed the following

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: $('#minifrm').serialize(),
    url: "CRUD/myfile.php?check=" + para + "&freq=" + freq + "&expire=" + expire,
    success: function (status) {
        if (status.success == false) {
            alert("Your details we not saved");
        } else {
            var checkstatus = status.toString();

            if (checkstatus === 'Already Exists')
            {
                alert("You are here");
            }
            if (checkstatus === '')
            {
                alert("There is nothing");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Currently it will echo "Already Exists" and alert "You are here" but if it doesn't exist it will not alert "There is nothing".

Comment: what are you returning from php file?

Comment: you are setting value here checkstatus = 'Already Exists'
make it
checkstatus == 'Already Exists'

Comment: Surely if `status.success` was false, it would call the `failed` callback not the `success` callback, right?

Comment: if you have an object that has `status.sucess`, surely `status.toString()` will have that `.sucess` part of the object?  Can you do a `console.log` of your status object in the else and show what the results are please

Answer (score 2):

Use double equal to `==` instead of single `=` for comparing two variable like this :

```
if(checkstatus == 'Already Exists')
  {
    alert("You are here");  
  }
```

Comment: Better yet, use triple equality `===`, this way there can be no question about truthy/falsy values.

Comment: Yes right, also we can use `trim()` for removing whitespaces in the result variable. Sometime we get whitespaces appended while getting response from server.

Comment: @TapuwaSimonMundeta Triple equal might not work as you are comparing different datetypes like string and integer. Use double equal to here

Comment: @Taps101 if you're comparing two different types, make sure you know the truthy and falsy values that the comparison will give you

Answer (score 0):

You used single equal to = means it will assign that value in variable in this way you will not get desired output currently in your case what happen when code execute if condition executed it will assign  'Already Exists' in checkstatus variable. So used Use double equal to ==. write your condition check code like below.

```
if (checkstatus == 'Already Exists')
            {
                alert("You are here");
            }
            if (checkstatus == 0)
            {
                alert("There is nothing");
            }
```

Comment: For some reason it will see 'Already Exists' but when I want checkstatus it doesn't go through.